# Matrix Representions

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

Let $ V=\{ f\in\text{func} (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}) : f(t) =\alpha \cos (t) +\beta \sin(t),  \alpha,  \beta \in \mathbb{C} \} $.

(a)  show that cos$(t) $,  sin$(t) $,  and  exp(-it), exp(it) both form a basis for $ V$.

(b) Find the change of basis matrix.

(c)  Find the matrix representation of $ D:V\to V $ with respect to both bases and check that the change of basis matrix gives the correct relationship between these two matrices. Where $D$ is the derivative function.

I am trying to get insight into this problem from linear algebra. It appears to have some intersection with Fourier analysis, which I don't know about. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be put on hold, see meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the vectors are given as "$\alpha cos(x)+ \beta sin(x)$" all that you need to do is show that cos(x) and sin(x) are *independent*.  That is, that A cos(x)+ B sin(x)= 0 (for all x) only A= B= 0.  And that's pretty close to "trivial".  Take x= 0 and $x= \pi/2$ and see what happens.

To see that $e^{ix}$ and $e{-ix}$ also form a basis use the fact that $cos(x)= \frac{e^{ix}+ e^{ix}}{2}$ and $sin(x)= \frac{e^{ix}- e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

For the "change of basis matrix" you want a matrix that multiplied by a column matrix with coefficients from the first basis gives the column matrix with coefficients from the second basis.  The first "basis vector", cos(x)= 1(cos(x))+ 0(sin(x)), would, as I said above, be written as $\frac{e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}}{2}= \frac{1}{2}e^{ix}+ \frac{1}{2}e^{-ix}$.  So we want our matrix to map $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.  Similarly with sin(x) to $\frac{e^{ix}- e^{-ix}}{2i}$ the matrix must map $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2i} \\ -\frac{1}{2i} \end{pmatrix}$.  Such a matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2i} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2i} \end{pmatrix}$.